# Access child method within livewallpaper service class

Tags: java, android, live-wallpaper

How does this child class access the parent class within livewallpaper service.

```
public class LiveWallpaperService extends WallpaperService
{
public static final String SHARED_PREFS_NAME="t_settings";
public static final String strSharedPrefs="t_settings";

@Override
public Engine onCreateEngine()
{       
    return new LiveWallpaperWallpaperEngine();
}

public static void updatePreferences()
{
    //This is the class that needs to access the child method.
    Log.w("yo", "resumed from main activity");
}

    public class LiveWallpaperWallpaperEngine extends Engine implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
    {   
         //This is the child method I'm trying to access.
         public void updatePreferencesB(){}'
```

I've tried using Abstract which I can't because it crashes the application also static doesn't allow me to make any changes to objects.

The

```
public static void updatePreferences
```

Is called when the Preferences Activity is destroyed, tested and works. Now I just need a way to find out how to access the child method of the main activity feed when the onDestroy is called.

Olly.

Comment: You seem to have implemented ``OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`` already and I can't help wondering what you need this static ``updatePreferences`` for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, short answer is: you can't. Part of being a `static` or class-level method means that you aren't part of any particular instance of the class. Without providing it with some mechanism for acquiring an instance -- perhaps by passing in a reference to your instance as a parameter -- you'll have to rethink how you're doing it.